# Difference between `<%#` and `<%=` and an asp.net ascx file?

Tags: asp.net

I understand that `<%=` is for returning a String

I seem to usually use `<%#` in my .ascx files.

For example the following works

`OnClientClick=<%# String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete barcode ({0})?');", Eval("BARCODE") ) %>`

The following does not work

`OnClientClick=<%= String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete barcode ({0})?');", Eval("BARCODE") ) %>`

Comment: It looks like your "this works" and "this doesn't work" are exactly the same... unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<%# indicates there's an evaluation function in there that takes in bound data and examines that data for a column or property in the [Eval()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval.aspx) function. It is specific to data binding in WebForms.

<%= just expects something that can be converted to a string. It will get confused by EVAL()

And finally there's the new

<%@ in MVC - which takes the string input, and Html encodes it to try to avoid XSS.

Comment: isn't the MVC notation  '<%:' ?

Comment: <%: outputs without encoding. In the WebForms view engine. Switch to razor and it's all @ :)